# JSONSchema to validate an array of strings containing specific items

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I am trying to specify an array of strings that must contain specific properties.
I would like to specify the required items for validation. 
In this example: uuid, template, createdOn, updatedOn. It must be an array of strings.

**My schema looks like this:**

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "$id": "56544e3c-e197-4602-8457-2c01dc6b12c5",
  "title": "The Root Schema",
  "type": "object",
  "additionalProperties": false,
  "required": ["attributes"],
  "properties": {
    "attributes": {
      "type": "array",
      "uniqueItems": true,
      "items": {
        "type": "string",
        "enum": ["uuid", "template", "createdOn", "updatedOn", "fields", "elements"]
      },
    }
  }
}
```

**and should validate against this:**

```
{
  "attributes": ["uuid", "template", "createdOn", "updatedOn"],
},

{
  "attributes": ["uuid", "template", "createdOn", "updatedOn", "fields", "elements"],
}
```

**but not this because of missing item 'updatedOn':**

```
{
  "attributes": ["uuid", "template", "createdOn", "fields", "elements"],
}
```

I already tried a lot with no success. Can anybody give me a hint?

Comment: Try to use `minItems: 6` and `maxItems: 6` together with `uniqueItems`, see more documentation here https://docs.mongodb.com/stitch/mongodb/document-schemas/#arrays

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `contains` keyword to make sure an array contains a certain item.

```
"allOf": [
  { "contains": { "const": "uuid" } },
  { "contains": { "const": "template" } },
  ...
]
```

Comment: thx I will try your solution as soon I am in the office again.